# what are the possible improvements in below string circular buffer implementation?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I needed to implement the circular buffer which need to hold the string as a element.

I come up with a below class prototype. but as i am newbie to c++, i think there should something better available to achieve same purpose.

Below is the class definition.

```
class circular_buffer {
    public:
        circular_buffer( int count ) : size( count ), index( 0 )
        {
            v.resize( size );
        }

        void add_element( const char* elem )
        {
            v[index] = elem;
            index = ( index + 1) % size;
        }

        bool is_element_exist( const char * elem )
        {
            auto itr = find_if( v.begin(), v.end(), [elem](string &o) { return o == elem; } );
            return ( itr != v.end() )
        }

    private:
        int size;
        int index;
        std::vector<std::string> v;
};
```

Is there any better solution possible? Are there any chance of improvement in above design?

I read somewhere about boost circular buffer but that is not a option for me.

**Edited as per suggestion by Martin zhai in his comment and answer.**

Comment: Do the code you show work? Do you only want a code-review? Then it's probably better to ask at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Code is working. I don't just want code review but i want to know about alternate better solution if available.

Comment: `add_element_to_circular_buffer` and `check_if_elem_present_in_circular_buffer` could be renamed to `add_elem` and `elem_exist`.

Comment: if you restrict buffer size to a power of two, you can eliminate "% size" and replace it with "& (size - 1)", which is faster (a bit mask instead of a division/remainder).

Comment: you could also pass in the elements as just a char instead of char *, since you only want 1 character. Might shave a tiny bit off.

Comment: @JasonLang I want complete string not just char

Answer (score 2):

Some opinions:

**1.** `itr` does not need to be a class member, since you just use it in `check_if_elem_present_in_circular_buffer()`.

You could remove `itr` in class definition, and declare it in the function by:

```
auto itr = find_if( v.begin(), v.end(), [elem](string &o) { return o == elem; } );
```

**2.** `check_if_elem_present_in_circular_buffer()` could be simplified:

```
bool check_if_elem_present_in_circular_buffer( const char * elem )
{
    auto itr = find_if( v.begin(), v.end(), [elem](string &o) { return o == elem; } );
    return (itr != v.end());
}
```